# Biting my other dog's tail

Tags: behavior

I have one handicapped Shih Tzu.  He doesn't have much feeling in his legs or tail.  However, every since my Shih Tzu came back from the groomer's, the Silky terrier that I adopted 2 months ago has been chomping at my other dog's feet and tail.  To the point of blood.  Suggestions?